# Logging into steam VIA ssh to update game

Tags: steam, technical-issues, linux, starbound

I just recently got a server and it is linux SSH. It has installed on it Starbound. Starbound has recently updated and I need to update it but with the instructions provided I cannot seem to get it to work. I keep getting Errors like so:

http://gyazo.com/4bc57a66bc1ff9b83e704917781a6bb9.png

**Here are the instructions I am following:**

> Updating your Starbound Server
>   Download Putty or another SSH client
>   login to your server by typing 'ssh root@YOURSERVERIP'
>   Now enter your servers password when prompted
>   change to your starbound servers directory 'cd /home/starbound/SteamCMD'
>   Now type 'vim ./update_starbound.sh'
>   On the line where you see YOURSTEAMACCOUNT and YOURSTEAMPASSWORD enter your information.
>   Now hit escape then hold 'shift + :' type 'wq!' then hit enter
>   Now you may do the following to patch your server.
>   'cd /home/starbound/server/linux64/'
>   'bspatch starbound_server starbound_server_patched starbound-loader.bspatch'
>   'chmod a+x starbound_server_patched'
>   'mv starbound_server starbound_server_org' hit y if prompted
>   'mv starbound_server_patched starbound_server'
>   Now you may follow the directions on starting your server and you're good to go!

Comment: Where did you get the instructions?

Comment: I would ABSOLUTELY caution against doing *any* of this from a security standpoint. **ESPECIALLY** the part where you're putting your steam account details into a file that's quite possibly world readable and may transmit those details who knows where.

Comment: https://tinderlight.us/starbound.php - I won this server from a Twitch.TV giveaway. I am super noob at SSH.. I do know the people who are sponsors with this company. Since Starbound requires steam login to be updated I guess I have to enter this info?

Comment: While I agree with @Shadur initially, this is done right now due to the Beta status; there's no dedicated server Steam App ID. This means you have to use a Steam ID that has Starbound purchased on it. The way I do it is a simple `rsync` from my local install to my server since each copy of Starbound contains the server binaries.

Answer (score 1):

You need to hit <kbd>i</kbd> to insert text into vim after the line where you type `vim ./update_starbound.sh`.  The errors you are seeing are coming from vim because you aren't in the correct mode.

Comment: Thanks Dave - I am still having this issue, when I hit "i" I then go to the "USERNAME PASSWORD" section and deleted it then put my information in it. Once I do that I press ESC, Hold down shift and type WQ!. The WQ clears everything out and then I press ! so it is the only thing there.. I then press enter and continue. Then I get those errors. I sent you a Twit, please check it out.

Comment: @EliteCow make sure that `wq` is lowercase - commands in vim are case sensitive. Holding the shift key was only supposed to be for the colon, I'd guess

Comment: Ah got it thanks sir! Now that I got that working it is saying
./launch_starbound_server.sh: ./starbound_server: /{��nux-x86-64.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory

I am guessing I messed something up when trying to figure this all out..

Comment: UPDATE:
So, if I do "ls" I get this:

http://gyazo.com/3083a0243be38e835e8c9f76df5db66e.png

but I do not know how to execute "launch_starbound_server.sh" as "cd /home/starbound/server/linux64 ./launch_starbound_server.sh" is not working. Any suggestions?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: @EliteCow You're doing `cd /home/starbound/server/linux64` and `./launch_starbound_server.sh` as two separate commands and not both at once, right? If so, what error is it giving when you try to run launch_starbound_server.sh?

Comment: Im getting this when I run it in two seperate commands, the same as running it together. http://gyazo.com/df058dfd7ca060d31cccc5f687ef8187.png

Could you add me on skype? Elite_Jake

Comment: @EliteCow I'm not sure since I have no experience with your host and don't even own starbound. From a quick google for the bad ELF interpreter error, it seems there may be a 32-/64-bit mismatch: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328250/centos-64-bit-bad-elf-interpreter